# SQL relational database: Data manipulation and calculations

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database

I have two tables. One is a Booking_Platform table with all hotel booking data. The second is a Customer_Country_Table which stores information for origins of each customer that booked hotels through the platform.

I have to calculate which country has the highest increase in bookings from 2017 to 2018.

I will give some sample data below for reference:

```
Booking_Platform_Info
Booking_Date    column2  column3....  column N .......  Origin_Country_ID 
20-dec-2016    ....................................          103
03-jan-2017    ....................................          101
09-feb-2017    ....................................          103
23-apr-2017    ....................................          102
06-oct-2017    ....................................          102
11-nov-2017    ....................................          103
05-jan-2018    ....................................          102
21-jan-2018    ....................................          102
26-feb-2018    ....................................          101
09-mar-2018    ....................................          101
11-may-2018    ....................................          103
10-sep-2018    ....................................          102
20-nov-2018    ....................................          101
07-dec-2018    ....................................          101
23-dec-2018    ....................................          101
31-dec-2018    ....................................          103
23-jan-2019    ....................................          103


Customer_Country_Info
Country_ID        Country_Name
101                  Italy
102                  Spain
103                  Portugal
```

It is a bit complicated for me, as I understand I have to first join the tables, then do a group by country, then count the total no. of bookings by year (probably another group by); and then compare the results to see which country has the highest positive difference in bookings from 2017-2018. I welcome any help with coding this problem.

In my example, country 101 Italy would be the answer because difference between bookings in 2018 and 2017 is highest (5-1=4)

*********Edit after comments

I am writing two queries to get booking totals by country ID for both 2017 and 2018

```
 SELECT CAST(booking_date AS DATE), COUNT(*) as number_of_bookings, origin_country_id FROM Booking_Platform_Info                
WHERE booking_date >= '2017-01-01' AND              
      booking_date < '2017-01-01'               
GROUP BY origin_country_id;             

 SELECT CAST(booking_date AS DATE), COUNT(*) as number_of_bookings, origin_country_id FROM Booking_Platform_Info                
WHERE booking_date >= '2018-01-01' AND              
      booking_date < '2019-01-01'               
GROUP BY origin_country_id;
```

Sorry for my lack of knowledge, but I am not aware how to join queries so that I could get the country id with the highest difference in bookings.

Comment: Break it down into steps. First write a query that gets the total for 2017 by country ID. Write a similar query for 2018. Join those two queries so you can calculate the differences and return the row with the highest difference. Finally, join that withthe country info table to get the country name.

Comment: The interesting columns are those that go from column2  to column N

Comment: @Barmar: Thanks for the information. I have tried to follow the steps and wrote queries for the first two steps. It's included in the edits. I don't actually know how to join queries. Could you please advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join those two queries to compare the counts.

You also shouldn't include `CAST(booking_date AS DATE)` in the `SELECT` list. It's not needed, and it will just be a randomly selected date from the year.

```
SELECT country_name
FROM (
    SELECT a.origin_country_id
    FROM (
        SELECT origin_country_id, COUNT(*) AS 2017_total
        FROM Booking_Platform_Info
        WHERE STR_TO_DATE(booking_date, '%d-%b-%Y')  BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-12-31'
    ) AS a
    JOIN (
        SELECT origin_country_id, COUNT(*) AS 2018_total
        FROM Booking_Platform_Info
        WHERE STR_TO_DATE(booking_date, '%d-%b-%Y') BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-12-31'
    ) AS b
    ORDER BY 2018_total - 2017_total
    LIMIT 1
) as t1
JOIN Customer_Country_Info AS t2 ON t1.origin_country_id = t2.origin_country_id
```

Comment: Thank you. Will the query be able to understand 23-jan-2017 as 2017-01-23 if I don't use CSAT?

Comment: The `booking_date` column should be a `DATE`, not `VARCHAR`.

Comment: If it's a string, you need to use `STR_TO_DATE()`. `CAST()` won't be able to do it by itself.